# Swift selector - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, selector, nstimer

I have a function:

```
func runRockRotation(rockSprite: SKSpriteNode){
    startRockRotationAnimation(rockSprite, isRock: true)
}
```

When I call it like this:

```
runRockRotation(rock)
```

it works, but I can't seem to be able to put it inside a NSTimer selector.

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "runRockRotation:", userInfo: rock, repeats: false)
```

Read a lot of forums, tried this:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "runRockRotation()", userInfo: rock, repeats: false)
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "runRockRotation(_)", userInfo: rock, repeats: false)
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "runRockRotation", userInfo: rock, repeats: false)
```

Also, tried without rock, using nil, but nothing seems to work.

Every time I get:

```
2015-04-10 15:49:03.830 Meh[1640:218030] -[__NSCFTimer runAction:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174166840
2015-04-10 15:49:03.832 Meh[1640:218030] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFTimer runAction:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174166840'
```

How do I call my function in a selector with a parameter? I know how to do that in Objective C, but can't seem to do it in Swift. All help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you calling timer? Is the timer being created in the class you have runRockRotation defined? You pass "self" as the target, maybe this isn't what you need?

Comment: use : `selector: "runRockRotation:"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the documentation for [`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)

You will see that

> The selector should have the following signature: `timerFireMethod:`
>   (including a colon to indicate that the method takes an argument).
>
> The
>   timer passes itself as the argument, thus the method would adopt the
>   following pattern:
>   `- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer`

Your function doesn't match this pattern, so the appropriate selector cannot be found.

Use something like -

```
func runRockRotationForTimer(_ timer: NSTimer){
    self.runRockRotation(timer.userInfo as? SKSpriteNode)
    timer.invalidate();
}
```

and schedule it using

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "runRockRotationForTimer:", userInfo: rock, repeats: false)
```

Comment: FWIW I also had to make my func public

Answer (score 2):

Also helps to make sure the target object (self in your case) is a subclass of NSObject

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: <THIS MUST BE NSOBJECT SUBCLASS>, selector: "runRockRotation:", userInfo: rock, repeats: false)
```